# Constant random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, constants

How do I plot the cumulative distribution function and probability mass function of the **constant random variable** $X(\omega)=2$ for all $\omega$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(X = c) = 1,$ then that equation is all that's necessary to show the PMF.

The CDF $F_X(x)$ is $0$ for $x < c$ and $1$ for $x \ge c.$

Here is a plot of the CDF for the case $c = 3.$

[image]

Comment: I do not follow the first line in your answer. I do follow the rest.

Comment: Also, your second line should be "...for $x\geq c$" and not "...for $x\geq 1$"

Comment: Thanks. Fixing typo. // You could add to the first part, for the PMF, something like 'Also $P(X \ne c) = 0.'$ But that follows from $P(X = c) = 1.$ Please ask again if anything remains unclear.

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753080/derivative-of-the-constant-cdf) ?

Answer (score 2):

The CDF is:
$$P(X\leq x) = \begin{cases}
  1 \quad \text{ if } x \geq 2 \\
  0 \quad \text{ if } x < 2 \\
\end{cases}$$

while the PMF is:
$$P(X = x) = \begin{cases}
  1 \quad \text{ if } x = 2 \\
  0 \quad \text{ if } x \not= 2 \\
\end{cases}$$